# Terraform helm_release upgrade

Tags: terraform, airflow

I have some terraform code that deploys the helm chart, currently I am running some Apache Airflow 2.0.1 and wanted to perform some upgrade with helm release

Old code

```
resource "helm_release" "airflow" {
  name          = "airflow"
  repository    = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart         = "airflow"
  reuse_values  = "true"
  version       = "8.2.0"
  recreate_pods = var.airflow_helm_recreate_pods

  values = [
    file(var.helm_file)
  ]

  # ... some set variables here
```

New code

```
resource "helm_release" "airflow" {
  name          = "airflow"
  repository    = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart         = "airflow"
  reuse_values  = "true"
  version       = "13.0.0"
  recreate_pods = var.airflow_helm_recreate_pods

  values = [
    file(var.helm_file)
  ]

  # ... some set variables here
```

This should target 2.3.3 application. I'am getting some strange error about fernet key

```
│ Error: execution error at (airflow/templates/config/secret.yaml:21:25):
│ PASSWORDS ERROR: The secret "airflow" does not contain the key "airflow-fernet-key"
│
│
│   with helm_release.airflow,
│   on airflow.tf line 145, in resource "helm_release" "airflow":
│  145: resource "helm_release" "airflow" {
```

Based on this documentation, there is some key like airflow-fernet-key
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/airflow/13.0.0?modal=template&template=config/secret.yaml

I already tried to delete & re-install providers as well as to make some upgrades but did not work.

Comment: are you providing `Values.auth.existingSecret` in the new code?

Comment: No. I just chnaged the helm release version from 8.2.0 to 13.0.0. At this moment I can make an upgrade by destroying the old release and then creating a new one and this is working fine but I am loosing rolling update functionality